# Promise pattern falling back multiple fetches

Tags: javascript

I'm using fetch promises to fall back through 3 API calls until one succeeds. I'm not sure what the best pattern is for that. I'd like to use something like this, where promise rejection is handled by the next `catch` and fetches the next URL.

The issue is that successfully resolved data is picked up by `.then(res => res.json())`

```
fetch(url1)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        if (data.status !== 'OK') {
            return Promise.reject()
        }

        return Promise.resolve(data)
    })
    .then(null, () => {
        return fetch(url2)
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        if (!data.success) {
            return Promise.reject()
        }

        return Promise.resolve(data)
    })
    .then(null, () => {
        return fetch(url3)
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        if (data.error) {
            return Promise.reject()
        }

        return Promise.resolve(data)
    })
```

The success checks are different for each function, so I can't easily use a loop that breaks on success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just group the optional API call and processing in the catch function:

```
fetch(url1)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    if (data.status !== 'OK') {
      return Promise.reject()
    }

    return Promise.resolve(data)
  }).catch(function() {
    return fetch(url2)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        if (!data.success) {
          return Promise.reject()
        }

        return Promise.resolve(data)
      });
  }).catch(function() {
    return fetch(url3)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        if (data.error) {
          return Promise.reject()
        }

        return Promise.resolve(data)
      })
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Promise.all or Promise.race, and wrap the checks on functions.

Comment: The goal is to make as few API calls as possible (stopping after one succeeds). Both of those make 3 calls.